# SO[FU] rejecting requests coming from Opera if "Turbo" mode is on

Tags: bug, status-declined, opera

Opera 10 has a nice turbo mode where all requests are re-routed to Opera's servers ( `global-turbo-x.opera-mini.net` ) where the pages are compressed and sent back to the client browser. Consequently all requests to a site arise from that server instead of the actual server.

Yesterday I was unable to access SO[FU] from Opera. Initially I thought SO[FU] was down, but when I checked from my iPhone, the sites were accessible. I tried again in Opera, this time with "Turbo" mode Off, and yep I was able to access. Turn it on, and SO[FU] just refuses connections.

[alt text http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/8494/serverrefusestoperformr.png](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/8494/serverrefusestoperformr.png)

Comment: Do you really need Turbo mode?

Comment: Yes. The place I'm at has a 2.5GB BW Cap. For a *month*.

Comment: That's quite a lot for a cap. You must be outside of Australia.

Comment: @Random I'm from India. Currently at my folks' place, where they have this connection as their usage isn't much. 

*Of course when I'm here the bill hikes up*

Comment: I use SO with Opera Mini all the time - no problems. I don't see how you can be so sure Opera is NOT to blame.

Comment: I have 2 Windows, one with Turbo, other without. Without turbo - it opens. With turbo - above message.

Comment: Are you playing Gnometris **and** Freecell **at the same time**?

Comment: Way to go Opera for trying to revive that "TURBO" button I had on the front my my 33mhz 386.

Comment: @snicker ahahaha I hear ya!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The value of this should be fairly limited, since

- we are pretty aggressive about making sure all our HTTP requests come back compressed
- the site itself has almost no images
- we don't host images here in posts (all external image hosts)
- we run `pngout` on all our .png images so they're as small as they can be

(now, there are exceptions around stuff that IIS7 has cached, like RSS feeds, which we haven't quite figured out. But in typical use of the site, 95% of your requests should be compressed. Verify in the sniffer if you like.. we have!)

edit: it looks like opera's "Turbo Mode" proxies are intentionally retrieving pages uncompressed and getting banned for anomalous bandwidth use per day. That's ... *[ironic](http://sadtrombone.com/)*.

Comment: Oh **Opera,** what are you doing?

Comment: that's *so Opera!* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That%27s_So_Raven

Comment: *it looks like opera's "Turbo Mode" proxies are intentionally retrieving pages uncompressed*

 Oh dear.

Comment: Opera, my dear, I do say... **fail.**

Comment: I just did a quick test with Opera Mini 4.2, 5.0, and Opera 10.50 with Turbo. Both of the Mini browsers requested compression while the desktop did not. Maybe Mini could be unblocked?

Comment: A bit old for a bump, but Opera seems to have gotten their act together.  Viewing SE sites with no major problems on Opera 36.0.2130.29.