# Is Opera Mini completely blocked from the SOFU sites?

Tags: support, blocked, opera-mini

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do you block Opera Mini?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48525/why-do-you-block-opera-mini)

I've been using Opera Mini to visit these sites pretty constantly ever since I joined (although most posting has been done via a PC). However, ever since Feb 19th I've been unable to access any of them - it just times out. Access via an online proxy (such as Bypass That) within Mini works fine. Is it possible that this relates to the behaviour of Opera Turbo observed in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36566/sofu-rejecting-requests-coming-from-opera-if-turbo-mode-is-on/36579#36579) (which has a major overlap with how Mini works)? The only reference I can find to Mini itself being blocked is the first comment on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40248/when-will-opera-support-be-fixed-on-so) (although the question itself is of no relevance).

Comment: Related question about Turbo, although the answer is phrased as "stop proxying", which translates as "do not use opera mini to visit this site" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36566/sofu-rejecting-requests-coming-from-opera-if-turbo-mode-is-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since discovered that the 'block' appeared to be localised. The Mini servers are hosted in different locations around the world, and I was unable to access the sites via Mini while in Asia (which would use the China-based servers). Now I'm in the UK, Mini works normally (presumably as the Norway servers haven't been 'blocked', if that's what it was).

Answer (score 2):

I guess, they blocked by IP address of high traffic, My Opera Turbo fails from Mid Jan, so yours might be different IP address.

<sub>PS: I've solved this by setting up my own proxy in a web hosting</sub>