# Why do you block Opera Mini?

Tags: support, status-completed, blocked, opera-mini

I know this is a duplicate.

I am getting quite frustrated because the procedure for accessing SOFU is quite involved:

- start Opera Mini
- wait for it to load
- go to SO
- wait until it times out
- close Opera Mini
- repeat above steps until SO finally loads

I emailed `team@stackoverflow.com` but they were no help. They said Opera Mini requests pages uncompressed, etc. which is not true.

Is there anything I can do? I mostly have access to SO through Opera Mini so this is quite important.

An alternative might be a mobile version of SOFU?

Comment: I have the same problem - so annoying

Comment: +1 This makes it hard for me to get to SO when I'm stopped at a red light.

Comment: @Jamesd: I agree. It is a real pain.

Comment: It's not true? evidence!

Comment: @Downvoter: Go to a site that shows HTTP headers with Opera Mini.

Comment: Screenshot is better

Comment: I am using Opera Mobile (Symbian) to access SOFU, no issue. Why the inconsistency? Opera Mobile uses compressed pages?

Comment: @o.k.w - Opera mobile doesn't route requests to a all-compressing proxy server ( a la Opera Mini/Turbo ).

Comment: Make sure and vote up this feature-request, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> They said Opera Mini requests pages uncompressed, etc. which is not true.

It is in fact true. Tell Opera to stop requesting data uncompressed through their turbo "service", and I'll gladly unban them.

edit: as a show of good faith I have unblocked the IP range to see if they have indeed fixed this problem. I reserve the right to be *even more cranky than usual* if our Mon - Tue logs show they haven't.

Comment: + 1 for use of the Ban-Hammer

Comment: Well I'll try contacting them... but I still think a mobile site would solve everything.

Comment: Everything except you're running a mobile version of the site which **will** be sucking bandwidth because of the uncompressed data being requested.

Comment: Thanks! This means a lot to me - much better access to SO.

Comment: +1 Jeff: bravo, bravo. I don't use Opera, but I think it's a worthy trial.

Comment: Had to test this out. Images (especially ads) look horrible, layout breaks here and there (mostly text bleeding out of elements), margins are applied in a weird way... in fact the native browser of the device I'm testing this on (iPod Touch) is better than Opera Mini, only thing Mini does better is loading the page faster (for obvious reasons).

Comment: @Esko Opera Mini _does_ have a tremendous share in developing nations where you cannot afford both a mobile and a computer.

Comment: @badp Business wise developing countries are irrelevant since if they can't afford two pieces of technology, they're not going to be a source of income for the company that should support them and thus there's no driving force for even trying. Isn't capitalism great?

Comment: @Esko The only thing SOIS sells to users is placement in its career searches.

Comment: @badp I don't think that the population you're referring to is prime employment material for any relevant job position available here. You're trying to justify the need for supporting Opera Mini by using a completely irrelevant demographic.

Comment: @Esko You're looking at it the wrong way. Jeff didn't block Opera Mini because of money or capitalism or cinism or hate, but because of technical issues. Read the post.

Comment: @badp Those technical issues mean that more effort is needed to get the site working on that platform. The users of that platform are highly irrelevant as a whole since they have either better options available or do not visit these sites anyway *(unless someone creates a very specific SE site for them, hmm...)* which means that the effort will ultimately be wasted. You just can't serve everyone.

Answer (score 6):

The problem couldn't possibly Opera Mini. Nope, no way. Gotta be SOFU's fault.

Comment: I agree. Definitely SOFU's fault.

Comment: I agree. Definitely SOFU's fault.

Comment: I agree. Definitely SOFU's fault.

Comment: I agree. Definitely SOFU's fault.

Comment: I agree. Definitely Opera...Dang it!

Answer (score 2):

Opera Mini works by proxying the site you're trying to access to somewhere in Norway (*well not really but it's plausible*), doing some **horrible** automatic content transformation and then transfers the "optimized" garble to your phone for viewing.

This process takes time and high volume sites such as SOFU don't really keep up to that process on the content transforming server end which means timeouts and such.

So there's really nothing anyone on the web can do about Opera Mini's functionality beyond some rudimentary hacking which usually just isn't worth the effort. Opera Mini used to be great, but nowadays it's already sailing on the Sea of Regression and its hull is already leaking...