# Opera Mini DOES request compressed data!

Tags: support, opera-mini

As per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48525/why-do-you-block-opera-mini) question, I need to make something clear:

**Opera Mini does support compressed data.**

Don't believe me? I went to http://www.ericgiguere.com/tools/http-header-viewer.html with my phone and sure enough:

> Accept-encoding: deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0

Still don't believe me?

See here:

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/phone.jpg

I hope that this makes it quite clear who supports what. If you want to give me a URL and have me visit it with my phone to verify this, I would be happy to.

**Update:** the headers above are from the Opera Mini *proxy* server, not my phone. When Opera Mini visits a page, my phone connects to their 'turbo' proxy, which in turn connects to `stackoverflow.com`. *When the proxy connects*, it fetches data with the above headers - indicating that it supports compressed data.

Comment: Your a programmer aren't you? Just make your own web browser and quit whining that Opera Mini isn't supported

Comment: @Earlz: You think it's easy to create a J2ME browser with built-in compression, compatibility with thousands of phones, and a massive server farm encoding pages for it? Gimme a break.

Comment: More insight: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36566/sofu-rejecting-requests-coming-from-opera-if-turbo-mode-is-on

Comment: What the hell does 'this time youre the bunny' mean?

Comment: @Ivo: There used to be a `im-a-bunny` tag.

Comment: @ear, *you're =o)

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstand.

Opera routes a lot of their "mini" and "mobile" requests through a compressing service they call "turbo". This is a kind of **proxy**.

This compressing services *requests all HTTP data in uncompressed format*, which it then compresses (using "max" compression) and returns to the browser. This is completely nonsensical and even a little ironic, since it uses tons of bandwidth .. sort of the opposite of turbo. Anyway, it could

> retrieve compressed -> decompress -> recompress

just as easily as it could

> retrieve uncompressed -> compress

The IP addresses of this poorly designed proxy are banned. If you can get the browser to correct DIRECTLY to our website from *YOUR* IP address, you won't be banned.

Take it up with Opera, Inc if you have an issue with this; from my perspective their proxy is banned forever until they fix the behavior.

Comment: And of course Jeff beats me by a few seconds lol

Comment: Their proxy is requesting data *compressed*. See the picture above. These headers are from their proxy server. The route the data takes after their servers have it is irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: as far as I'm concerned this just another in a long string of idiocy from Opera. They need to either stop making web browsers, or adopt WebKit as their engine.

Comment: Well... webkit is a good idea. I'll agree with you there.

Comment: @Jeff: The headers above *are* from the proxy. **Not** my phone.

Comment: You mention that `'it could retrieve compressed -> decompress -> decompress just as easily as it could retrieve uncompressed -> compress'`. This is not true. Opera Mini uses a proprietary format to deliver content from their servers to the phones called OBML. It's not gzip.

Comment: @George: so they could retrieve compress -> decompess -> compress into their proprietary format, then.

Comment: No... when their proxy server retrieves gzip data, there is no simple way to convert that to their OBML format. They would have to decompress and recompress.

Comment: @George:  That's exactly what Jeff said... what are you getting at?

Comment: @James: Oh right... I misunderstood. BUT they still are sending `accept-encoding` headers that suggest compressed data is accepted.

Comment: I think you should stop whining, as Jeff will *never* unban it, so forget about it (and try jQuery) @george

Comment: @Downvoter: it isn't totally banned anyway - I'm using it right now. Nobody is complaining about that, are they?

Answer (score -2):

Come on George, you can say it: "I designed the Opera Turbo proxy" ;)

Comment: I can't take credit for something so awesome :)