# Since the CDN change static content no longer loads using online proxy servers

Tags: support, cdn

I wanted to ask an anonymous question (which is valid, interesting and on-topic) that involves me admitting to a crime. So I wanted to use an online proxy service such as http://zend2.com/, as I've done a few times in the past, but it won't load all the static content.

What can I do?

Comment: what about impersonating as a mobile device?

Comment: hey @balpha why is this not considered a bug? Shouldn't it just work, like all other websites do and like it worked before?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because your proxy service can't handle compressed responses. ([Example for a stylesheet resource pulled from SO through the proxy](http://zend2.com/Def.php?u=Oi8vY2RuLnNzdGF0aWMubmV0L3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cvYWxsLmNzcz92PTNlOGVkNGI5M2RkOQ==&b=5))

<strike>SO/SE famously [force compressed responses on clients](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36566/sofu-rejecting-requests-coming-from-opera-if-turbo-mode-is-on).</strike>

There's a number of proxy services that have this problem, but judging from the URL structure, they all seem to be based on the same product.

Proxify.com seems to be able to deal with SO's style sheets fine. [Example](http://proxify.com/p/011010A1000100/687474703a2f2f737461636b6f766572666c6f772e636f6d2f)

Comment: this is totally incorrect, AFAIK, but I'll check with Ben on the CDN policies. We don't force, we just blocked Opera's crazy IP addresses at one point

Comment: @Jeff ah, okay. It seems to be a phenomenon limited to whatever proxy product that service is using (although I'm fairly sure it's a compression problem)

Comment: hey Pekka, if it's a compression problem I don't see how it used to work before.. Unless the compression system was recently changed

Comment: @Kop well, they started delivering their static data through the CDN, so it may be a miscommunication between the CDN and the proxy