# Stack Exchange sites not rendering static assets correctly

Tags: support, design

This is happening a lot lately. Just now it didn't happen, but you know how it looks (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95428/stack-overflow-does-not-render-correctly-from-work) for a screenshot).

I was worried that this could be a duplicate, but:

a) It's not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185136/stackoverflow-static-assets-not-loading), because I don't use [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

b) It's not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95428/stack-overflow-does-not-render-correctly-from-work) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96060/since-the-cdn-change-static-content-no-longer-loads-using-online-proxy-servers?rq=1), because I don't use any kind of proxy

c) It's not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166251/all-css-rules-missing), because that's supposedly been solved and was a temporary [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) issue.

d) It could be a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29431/radomly-missing-css?rq=1), but I'm not using any [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent) client or anything, although it could be the router. How do I fix it if that's the case?

I've tried clearing the cache, and switching browsers, and apparently the only thing that works is connecting to Stack Overflow through [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) (gives me a different IP address - BTW this might prove item d is not the case). Are you using any kind of IP address-based caching?

Surprisingly, at this hour it renders fine and quickly. Might be some kind of traffic overload?

I'm on [Ubuntu 13.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_13.04_.28Raring_Ringtail.29) (Raring Ringtail) using Firefox 22.0.

Comment: When it doesn't work, what happens when you hit a CDN resource URL directly? e.g. https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js

Comment: I'll wait until the problem comes back, and edit this answer. Right now it's working fine, but I expect it shows up again in the afternoon.

Comment: Let me know via an @Nick here and we'll see what your issue it.  So far it's been proxies users were not aware of blocking https traffic.

Comment: +1 for thorough dup search

Comment: @NickCraver Now that the problem is at hand ... Trying that url gives me "Problem loading page" in firefox, and in curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cdn.sstatic.net.