# Functionality regression on Opera Mini

Tags: bug, status-declined

As of today, I can no longer access Javascript elements, when browsing from Opera Mini 6.1.25570 on Symbian. For example, I cannot add a comment or drop down the tools menu; I can't switch views in the profile pages. Is it me, or has Stack Exchange changed?

Comment: I suppose you're using the mobile theme?

Comment: Did you activate the "Turbo" or whatever the name for Opera's "We'll execute the JS on our Proxy for you; no need to thank us for breaking the site, you're welcome" mode is? (Btw, I'm surprised that it ever worked)

Comment: Yes I'm using mobile theme. @balpha  Mini only operates in turbo mode. It's what makes SO usable on a phone. It did work well before.

Answer (score 10):

This may or may not be related to [SO[FU] rejecting requests coming from Opera if "Turbo" mode is on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36566/sofu-rejecting-requests-coming-from-opera-if-turbo-mode-is-on).

Either way, Opera Mini is not a browser we support. The concept of "execute the JS somewhere else on your behalf" is just way too broken to even start thinking about debugging it, and, as that other post shows, the Turbo does not exactly have a track record of awesomeness.

As I commented, I'm even surprised that it worked until yesterday. This suggests this may be a temporary issue; there certainly were no huge JavaScript changes yesterday.

This has nothing to do with us "liking" Opera Mini or not – this has to do with the fact that Opera Mini adds a whole other dimension to debugging issues, and this extra work is not well spent on a browser that on Stack Overflow has a market share of 0.1%, a mere tenth of the  (unsupported as well) IE6. We'd rather spend our time on making the sites work with browsers that either are used by a significant number of users, or that at least work the way a browser can be expected to work.

Comment: You might think it is way too broken, but I don't agree. It has worked fantastically for a long time for me. And I can't for the life of me understand why you don't want to support Opera Mini. This is by far the best mobile browsing experience on many devices. I must say I'm unimpressed by your attitude which seems to be, "we don't like your browser, we think it's rubbish, tough". It shouldn't matter what you think of my browser!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Updated my answer.

Comment: That other post is a little irrelevant. And I don't don't think you should write off Opera solely on the basis of that. My preference for Opera Mini is that it reformats pages to make them readable. I know no browser that does it better for my device. Anyway, you make it clear that you aren't interested in supporting this excellent product.

Comment: there is the Opera Mini simulator, but I'm not touching Java to run it... http://www.opera.com/mobile/demo/

Comment: @Jeff normal service has been resumed with mini. Could easily be due to changes at Opera. Just so that you know, I prefer Opera to my phone's Webkit browser because it reformats the content to be accessible on the phone. I'm not using it to reduce bandwidth.