# Problem with mobile layout on Opera Mini

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, mobile-web, opera-mini

I am using Opera Mini 7.0.30697 on my Nokia C6-00 (Symbian S60 5th edition) and the layout is broken, here are the screenshots, on native browser it even not mobile, but the full site layout, so it is very difficult for me to use SO. I've tested it on iOS device and it works just great, uncomparable with that what I see on my device.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 3):

Opera Mini is not a browser we support.

Comment: what a pity, because I have no other option :( do you plan to support it in future?

Comment: No. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102010/functionality-regression-on-opera-mini/102103#102103

Comment: ok, even if you don't want to support the best mobile browser, maybe you can add support for my native browser? I mean that it should be just some IF statement to make sure that on my native browser I also will see the mobile layout and not the full one

Comment: There's a "mobile" link at the bottom of the page to switch to the mobile layout.

Comment: but it takes out from me a lot of KBytes to open full site which cost money