# Am I infringing on Stack Exchange's copyright with this?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, opera-mini

I've made this because I'm a regular 15x7 mobile user, and I can't log in to the mobile version of Stack Overflow.

I don't see any log in buttons: log in with Facebook, log in with Google, log in with Yahoo, etc. Except login with open ID

Once I spent 5 hours searching for a solution to this problem.  At last, I found that it's just that Stack Overflow doesn't show a log in button in mobile version.

So I've just stolen the log in action URL and made a button which is now visible from any mobile browser.

Is that wrong ?

see: http://stackoverflow.yn.lt

Comment: Strange that you don't see any of the OpenID login buttons.  Maybe this would be better as a bug report instead?

Comment: Yes sure, for you guys its strange, because you dont know how stackoverflow looks like from a mobile browser, "operamini".
Have you ever used operamini browser ?

Comment: [Opera mini isn't supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140201/133693). (and honestly, it's not a "proper" browser - more like thin client wrapper where everything is handled by Opera's servers)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any copyright infringement here. It's just links ([deep links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking) but still just links).