# Stack Exchange buttons not working on Nokia 7230

Tags: support, mobile-web

Recently I tried logging into my Anime and Manga SE from a Nokia 7230. Everything showed up fine. But I wasn't able to log in, as the **log in** button did not work. Thinking that it must have been a minor error, I tried several other buttons such as **ask a question**. Surprisingly, none of them worked. I know the phone's quite old, literally and technologically. But I'm curious to know the reason to why this happened.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need may have the information you're looking for. It maybe a little tough to troubleshoot exactly what is the missing link though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [these phone specs from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/mobile/phone/7230/specifications/), the browser is Opera Mini. [Opera Mini is not supported on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140201/262755). ([see also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102010/functionality-regression-on-opera-mini/102103#102103) and [also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177509/262755))

Comment: Shame. Opera Mini is awesome. It's the only browser that is really usable on non-wifi, non-3G connections.